# create 3D (n:m:k) matrix in matlab using array 2D (i:3)

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

I need a 3D matrix in matlab, I have another 2D matrix (7570x3) too,
 The 3D matrix should have zero number except of all dimensions in 2D matrix that should have 1 value. How can I do that.

i.e. 2D matrix (1,:) = 28,64,27 then 3d(27,64,27) should be 1

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `a` is your 2-d matrix, and `b` is the 3-d one, use `sub2ind` as follows:

```
b=false(max(a));  % preallocate memory for a logical zeros matrix b
b(sub2ind(size(b),a(:,1),a(:,2),a(:,3))) = 1;
```

Check to see what  `max(a)` gives you to see if you can host a 3-d matrix of `size(max(a)` to begin with. Since you are interested in a logcial matrix (ones and zeros), the size of that matrix in memory is the same as the # of elements, `n*m*l`, so a 1000x1000x1000 will take 1 GB.

Note, it very well may be that `b` is very sparse,  if that is the case you can refer to [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/247430) to see how to deal with it. Know that at the moment, and to the best of my knowledge, matlab doesn't support 3d sparse matrices. So you may want to check [this option](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29832-n-dimensional-sparse-arrays) from the FEX. When I think of it, you already have a sparse look-up table of the 3D matrix! it is just your 2D matrix you started with...

Comment: see my edit regarding the full matrix use for the case it is a logical matrix. I've used `false` to preallocate instead of zeros. this is more memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I changed your code to make it make in for non-integer matrix too

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @natan

for non-integer matrix also can use:

```
b=false(floor(max(a)));  % preallocate memory for a logical zeros matrix b
b(sub2ind(size(b),floor(a(:,1)),floor(a(:,2)),floor(a(:,3)))) = 1;
```

or use round function:

```
b=false(round(max(a)));  % preallocate memory for a logical zeros matrix b
b(sub2ind(size(b),round(a(:,1)),round(a(:,2)),round(a(:,3)))) = 1;
```